# WPF - Simple Serialization of Rich Text Format (RTF) Data through its FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, serialization, rtf

I have a class called Location:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isAnOption { get; set; }
    public double distanceFromYaelsParents { get; set; }
    public double distanceFromGabrielsParents { get; set; }
    public FlowDocument notes { get; set; }
}
```

`notes` (of type `FlowDocument`) takes the contents of a WPF RichTextBox I have on my window.

I want to use a simple serialization in order to save objects created from this class to a binary file (and later read them). Let's say the item is called `location`:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(dataFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    bin.Serialize(stream, location);
}
```

So, as long as the `FlowDocument` is not included, everything is cool. I don't seem to manage serializing that one.

Can it be done? or alternatively - is there a better way to binary (not XAML) save and read the contents of a RichTextBox with images and formatted text in it?

Please elaborate, I'm pretty new to these things.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlowDocument is not serializable. See David Ward's answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447856/saving-flowdocument-to-sql-server) for a possible solution.

Basic idea: convert the FlowDocument to XAML (XML) and serialize it.

In your case, I'd exclude the FlowDocument property from serialization and instead have a string property which converts to/from FlowDocument in the getter/setter.

Comment: Phillip, thanks. I'll look into the link ypu provided and try XAML-ing and then serializing. The thing is that is if I take the string off the RTF, I'll lose pasted images...