# FlowDocument Xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, flowdocument

I have FlowDocument as a part of another composite object, what must be serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class RichTextSerializationWrapper
{
     public FlowDocument Document { get; set; }
}
```

So, I want serialize RichTextSerializationWrapper as follows:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RichTextSerializationWrapper));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
serializer.Serialize(writer, richTextSerializationWrapper);
writer.Close();
```

And I, of course, get exception:

> There was an error reflecting type
>   'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument'.

So, anybody know ways to serialize FlowDocument object into XML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question: [Saving FlowDocument to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447856/saving-flowdocument-to-sql-server)

Binary and XAML serialization are supported.