# Best format for wpf text file

Tags: c#, wpf, text, format

Which of yaml, html, xml, json etc, is best suited for large text blocks and formatting (headings, paragraphs, italics etc)? Also taking into account that it's for use in a wpf app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that standards such as Office Open XML or XPS use XML to store large documents, I'd suggest XML is likely the best choice.

If you look at some of the document choices for WPF, you will see that XML is a natural choice. Whatever you represent in XAML is XML. A FlowDocument can be serialized to XML as well (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573739/flowdocument-xml-serialization) answer).

You will find further information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/documents-in-wpf).