# WPF - Avoid getting TextChanged event triggered on a File load on RichTexBox

Tags: c#, wpf

**Question**: Is there any way to detect the occurrence of a file load in a [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview) (`RTB`) of a `WPF` app? I haven't find such an event in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8#events) list of events; or maybe there is some event in that list that can be used for a work around to achieve the following:

**Background** I'm allowing user to [load a file in the RTB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-save-load-and-print-richtextbox-content) and close it after making changes (if needed). But before the user closes the file my app checks if the changes were made by placing `bTextChanged` flag in the [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event. But I noticed that the `TextChanged` event is triggered even when a file is loaded. And even worst, the event is triggered for every character of the newly loaded file - that eventually can degrade the performance of the app if the loaded file is too long. so maybe there is a work around to make the `TextChanged` event triggered only when a text in the file is changed after the file was loaded.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string sgFileName = "";
    bool bTextChanged = false;
    ....
    ....
        private void BtnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                sgFileName = dlg.FileName;
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sgFileName, FileMode.Open);
                TextRange range = new TextRange(mainRTB.Document.ContentStart, mainRTB.Document.ContentEnd);
                range.Load(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
        }

        private void MainRTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            bTextChanged = true;
        }

    private void BtnCloseDocument_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bTextChanged)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Content has changed, do you want to save the changes?", "Content has Changed!", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
....
....
}
```

Comment: Can't you just unhook the text changed handler, load file, hook the handler back up? Alternately, convert the document to a string before and after and compare the two. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447856/saving-flowdocument-to-sql-server

Comment: @Andy Your suggestion of unhooking and hooking back the handler worked (thank you). But I read that more needs to be done when hooking and unhooking  . I just used one liner for unhooking and one liner for hooking back. Is there anything else that I need to be done? It's just a simple app with a simple `TextChanged` handler shown in my post.

Comment: What else did you read needs doing?  I wouldn't think there was anything else.

Comment: @Andy Your suggestion seems to be correct but when I read some responses such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/1232087) along with some other responses there it seems they are doing lot more than what I did using your suggestion.

Comment: @Andy You suggestion working for me so far (thank you). If you like you can convert your comment into a `response` and I'll mark it as an `answer` so other users can benefit from your response, as well.